# Select data at a particular level from a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas Dataframe with a MultiIndex(Z,A):

```
             H1       H2  
   Z    A 
0  100  200  0.3112   -0.4197   
1  100  201  0.2967   0.4893    
2  100  202  0.3084   -0.4873   
3  100  203  0.3069   NaN        
4  101  203  -0.4956  NaN
```

Question: How can I select all items with A=203?
I tried `df[:,'A']`  but it doesn't work. Then I found [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#cross-section-with-hierarchical-index) in the online documentation so I tried:
`df.xs(203,level='A')`
but I get:
"`TypeError: xs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'`"
Also I dont see this parameter in the installed doc(`df.xs?`):
"Parameters ---------- key : object Some label contained in the index, or partially in a MultiIndex axis : int, default 0 Axis to retrieve cross-section on copy : boolean, default True Whether to make a copy of the data"
Note:I have the development version.

Edit: I found [this thread](http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/16070/6393/). They recommend something like:

```
df.select(lambda x: x[1]==200, axis=0)
```

I still would like to know what happened with df.xs with the level parameter or what is the recommended way in the current version.

Comment: Which version are you using? Apparently `level` was added at [version `0.7.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#v-0-7-0-february-9-2012).

Comment: Well apparently that's the problem, i am on 0.6.1, I installed from git but somehow i am still on 0.6.1, thanks, should I close the question, if so, how?

Comment: You can write-up an answer with the reason for the problem and alternative solution and accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies in my assumption(incorrect) that I was in the dev version while in reality I had 1.6.1, one can check the current installed version with:

```
import pandas
print pandas.__version__
```

in the current version `df.xs()` with the level parameter works ok.

Answer (score 4):

Not a *direct* answer to the question, but if you want to select more than one value you can use the "slice()" notation:

```
import numpy
from pandas import  MultiIndex, Series

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
              ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = Series(numpy.random.randn(8), index=index)

In [10]: s
Out[10]:
first  second
bar    one       0.181621
       two       1.016225
baz    one       0.716589
       two      -0.353731
foo    one      -0.326301
       two       1.009143
qux    one       0.098225
       two      -1.087523
dtype: float64

In [11]: s.loc[slice(None)]
Out[11]:
first  second
bar    one       0.181621
       two       1.016225
baz    one       0.716589
       two      -0.353731
foo    one      -0.326301
       two       1.009143
qux    one       0.098225
       two      -1.087523
dtype: float64

In [12]: s.loc[slice(None), "one"]
Out[12]:
first
bar      0.181621
baz      0.716589
foo     -0.326301
qux      0.098225
dtype: float64

In [13]: s.loc["bar", slice(None)]
Out[13]:
first  second
bar    one       0.181621
       two       1.016225
dtype: float64
```